# error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘std::_List_iterator<int>’)

Tags: c++, std, stdlist

Hello im trying to print a list of ints and i keep getting that erro.

I have a structure that have a list on it.

```
struct faceFiguration{

    int faceID;
    list<int> setofVertices;

};
```

And i have a list of that sructure

```
 list<faceFiguration> pattern;
```

and heres where i get confuse, i trie to print the lists here:

```
void PrintFaces(){

      currentFace = pattern.begin();
      while(currentFace != pattern.end()){

        cout << currentFace -> faceID << endl;

        for(auto currentVertices = currentFace->setofVertices.begin(); currentVertices != currentFace->setofVertices.end(); currentVertices++){

          cout << currentVertices;

        }

        cout << '\n';
        currentFace++;
      }

    }
```

This is the full message error

`error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘std::__cxx11::list<int>’)`

Comment: `cout << *currentVertices;`

Comment: The error messages in your title and on the bottom of your question don't match, typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already gotten answers telling you to dereference the iterator:

```
for(auto currentVertices = currentFace->setofVertices.begin();
    currentVertices != currentFace->setofVertices.end();
    currentVertices++)
{
    cout << *currentVertices;   // dereference
}
```

You could however do that automatically by using a range-based for loop:

```
for(auto& currentVertices : currentFace->setofVertices) {
    cout << currentVertices;    // already dereferenced
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the error message really belongs to the line that causes the problem here (have you tried `<<`-ing the list itself before?), but

```
cout << currentVertices;
```

tries to invoke `operator <<` with a `std::ostream` reference (the `std::cout`) and  an iterator into a `std::list`. That doesn't work, because the iterator type doesn't have this operator (why should it). However, iterators are modeled after pointers, and hence allow for dereferencing to access the element they are referring to. Long story short; this should work:

```
cout << *currentVertices;
```

where the `*` in front of `currentVertices` is the dereferencing and yields an `int&` (reference to the underlying list element).

Answer (score 1):

`currentVertices` is an iterator here. It's an object that acts as a pointer. You cannot print it with `cout`. But yes, you can print out the value that the iterator is pointing at. To do so you have to put a `*` before the iterator. That is, `*currentVertices`. (Read as `content of currentVertices`)

So, the summary is

1. `currentVertices` is an iterator (or pointer if you wanna say) and `*currentVertices` is the `content of that iterator`.
2. You need to `cout` the `content of iterator` not the `iterator`

Comment: Agree, just! You **could** print the pointer by overloading `<<` which is not a good idea, bit it's **possible** :D

Comment: Yes, but i tried to answer as simple as possible. So I avoided operator overloading and stayed with the default one.

Comment: Thanks!! you saved mi life

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned

```
 cout << currentVertices;
```

attempts to print an iterator. But there is no overload for `operator<<` that takes a second parameter of this type. Either dereference the iterator

```
 //      V
 cout << *currentVertices;
```

or simplify the whole loop:

```
for(const auto &currentVertices : currentFace->setofVertices){
    cout << currentVertices;
}
```